# How can I set SIFT diameter/scale/magnifier in python opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I am trying to get SIFT to sample a larger area of the image when calculating the descriptors so it could describe larger objects (i.e., each descriptor would represent a larger patch in the image). The constructor signature of OpenCV accepts only the arguments stated below, which none of them seems to be relevant.

OpenCV constructor signature:

```
SIFT_create(nfeatures=None, nOctaveLayers=None, contrastThreshold=None, edgeThreshold=None, sigma=None)
```

The relevant part of my script:

```
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create(nfeatures=NUM_SIFT_FEATURES) 
kp, desc = sift.detectAndCompute(image, None)
```

Thanks!

Clarification:
I am looking for a parameter similar to "size" in the following implementation: https://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_dsift.html

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Can you give some examples or clarify further?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! SIFT calculates features analyzing the image in different layers (octaves). You could increase the number of octaves to create a "denser" representation of the image. I am not sure if this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: @smttsp, I added clarification.

Comment: @Grillteller, Thanks! Yes, this is what I was looking for.